# Error after running Terraform Plan-Error: AccessDeniedException: status code: 403,

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am recieving this error after running `terrafrom plan`

```
│ Error: AccessDeniedException: 
│   status code: 403, request id: aafb7939-5268-431d-b939-23c03b7887fe
```

The lack on detail in the error message is making this difficult for me to pinpoint the cause of this error. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

I have been working on this project for sometime, and my permissions have not changed within the project enviroment as far as i"m aware.

A colleage is able to run the same command with no error messages from his machine, and the plan competles succesfully.

I have ran `rm -Rf .terraform` then `terraform init` followed by `terrafrom plan`. However I still get the same error message.

Thankyou to anyone who can be of assistance.

Comment: Terraform normally displays way more error details. Two things you can try additionally: look up the request id in AWS CloudTrail and / or run terraform with debug logs https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 running in DEBUG has pointed in the right direction to resolve the issue.